# Draw points in a graph

Tags: java, graph, processing

`I have an array that every row is a day and 1st column means month, 2nd: day, 3rd: hour, 4th: minute and 5th:second of the sunrise.

I manage to the draw the graph, but I can't draw the line of the values of the array. The x axis is for the days of the year and y axis is the times of sunrise.
The original array has 365 columns, but I thought gicing the example of 4 would be enough.

```
int[][] Info_Sun = {
                
                      {  1  ,  1  ,  8  ,  23  ,  2 }  ,
                      {  1  ,  2  ,  8  ,  23  ,  9 }  ,
                      {  1  ,  3  ,  8  ,  23  ,  13 }  ,
                      {  1  ,  4  ,  8  ,  23  ,  15 }  ,
                      {  1  ,  5  ,  8  ,  23  ,  16 }  ,
                      {  1  ,  6  ,  8  ,  23  ,  14 }  ,
                      {  1  ,  7  ,  8  ,  23  ,  10  }  ,
             };

float positionX, positionY;
float sunset_pixel, sunrise_pixel, pixel_X, distance;
PFont f;     

void setup(){
    size(1500, 800);
    background(255, 255, 211);
    
    line(220,height/2+200,width-200,height/2+200);                   
    line(width/4-155,55,width/4-155,600);                                
    distance=-21.5;
    for(int s=1; s<25; s++){
  
          line(220,height/2+200+distance,width-200,height/2+200+distance);
          f= createFont("Consolas", 16, true);                  
          textFont (f,14);
          fill(0);
          text(s,200,height/2+200+distance);
          text("Sortida i posta (hora)", 100, 50);
          text("DIES DE L'ANY", 1200, 615);
          
          distance-=21.5;
          point(220, 220);
  }
  pixel_X=25;
    
  for (int i=0; i<Info_Sun.length; i++){
        sunrise_pixel=Info_Sun[i][2]*pixel_X+(Info_Sun[i][3]*pixel_X)/60+(Info_Sun[i][4]*pixel_X)/3600;
        strokeWeight(3);
        stroke(255,0,0);
        point (Info_Sun[i][1]+220, sunrise_pixel);      
    
    }
    
}
```

Comment: I love this question. Can you edit the code and make it runnable?

Comment: Also, remember to follow the [posting guidelines](/help/how-to-ask): look at your question after posting it, and at the very least [edit] it to fix the [markdown](/markdown) errors it has.

Comment: I did some modifications. I hope this helps to understand it better and runnable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified your code a bunch to simplify it for readability reasons; it may be that you need some of the changes I made for your own code so don't take it the wrong way, but making these modifications helped me to analyze your code.

I noticed that you used pixels instead of lines to link the 'points' of the graph. It makes sense in some contexts but here I choose to use line segments instead. Also, I coded it in a way that uses only the seconds instead of a real month-day-hour-minute-second line, because if I had you would have seen only a straight line. I wanted you to see the actual curve.

So you understand that my code here isn't a copy-and-paste solution to your issue, but instead a methodology that aims to let you understand the principle behind the graph lines.

Here what it'll look like:

[image: graph]

To draw a line, you need 2 sets of coordinates: the 1st point and the 2nd point. That's pretty easy to get the basic informations needed by using the `Info_Sun` array. The only difficulty is to translate these into actual coordinates. It's way easier when you remember these points:

- The (0,0) point of this graph's coordinates is actually the (220, 600) point.
- The (0,0) point of the sketch is in the left-up corner of the sketch.
- The X axis coordinates increases when you go right.
- The Y axis coordinates increases when you go down.

So you need to know these 2 distances to be able to calculate a point's coordinates:

- The distance between 2 points on the X axis.
- The distance between 2 points on the Y axis.

Which are being stored here in the variables `distanceX` and `distanceY`. By now you probably have guessed where I'm going with that but I'll go on anyway: the coordinates of a point are as follow:

```
X == 220 + distanceX * (Index of the point + 1)
Y == 600 - distanceY * Index of the point
// '+ 1' because arrays starts at 0 so day 1 is at index 0
```

Of course, you have to be aware that you'll need to calculate these coordinates of 2 points every time you draw a line: for the point at the current index, and for the point at index+1. So you can link those 2 points.

This said, here's some code that reflects what I just said. You will notice my modifications in the first part of the code; they are not that important. The part that interests you is at the end.

```
int[][] Info_Sun = {

  {  1, 1, 8, 23, 2 }, 
  {  1, 2, 8, 23, 9 }, 
  {  1, 3, 8, 23, 13 }, 
  {  1, 4, 8, 23, 15 }, 
  {  1, 5, 8, 23, 16 }, 
  {  1, 6, 8, 23, 14 }, 
  {  1, 7, 8, 23, 10  }, 
};

float positionX, positionY;
float sunset_pixel, sunrise_pixel, pixel_X, distanceX, distanceY;
PFont f;     

void setup() {
  size(1500, 800);
  background(255, 255, 211);

  // drawing axis and titles
  // modified for readability
  line(220, 600, 1300, 600);                   
  line(220, 600, 220, 55);                                
  distanceY=21.5;

  f= createFont("Consolas", 16, true);                  
  textFont (f, 14);
  fill(0);
  // Hours
  for (int i=0; i<24; i++) {
    line(220, 600-(distanceY*i), 1300, 600-(distanceY*i));
    text(i, 200, 600-(distanceY*i));
  }
  // Days
  distanceX = (1300-220)/(Info_Sun.length+1);
  for (int i=1; i<=Info_Sun.length; i++) {
    line(220+distanceX*i, 600, 220+distanceX*i, 55);
    text(i, 220+distanceX*i, 630);
  }
  text("Sortida i posta (hora)", 100, 50);
  text("DIES DE L'ANY", 1200, 615);

  //// drawing curves
  strokeWeight(3);
  stroke(255, 0, 0);

  // THIS IS THE PART WHERE I DRAW THE CURVE
  // Using only the seconds so you see a curve and not a straight line
  for (int i=0; i<Info_Sun.length-1; i++) {
    line(220+distanceX*(i+1), 600-distanceY*Info_Sun[i][4], 220+distanceX*(i+2), 600-distanceY*Info_Sun[i+1][4]);
    // Here I calculate 2 points per loop, one for everyday
    // so then I link every day by tracing a line between them, and as I start with the day 1 (which is at the index 0 in your table) I use index 0 and 1 for my first line
    // that's why loop ends at 'i<Info_Sun.length-1': else I would go out of the bounds of the array
  }
}
```

I'm sure you can adapt this principle to your own ends. I hope this helps!